# How to find first cached date and time of a website?

Tags: duplicate-content, googlebot, google-cache

I found some of my webpage contents has been copied in other website. I need to check the cache date and time of both pages so that i can compare and guess which page is original and which one is duplicate according to Google. Because i know that if Google found two webpages with same content, it consider the first cached page by Google bot as unique.

Is there any online tool for checking that? or other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the current cache date & time of a page in Google's index by clicking the small arrow in the SERPS, as in this screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbcrY.png

or by searching in Google for this phrase:   cache:*addwebsitehere.com*

e.g: `cache:google.com`

However ,Google updates it's cache all the time, so you can't find the initial cache. You could try using the [Wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php). The way back machines has caches of many websites that can some times go back many years.

Comment: I know this Moobot.. I need to compare both page's cache date and time. I already used Wayback machine and it didn't help me completely. Anyhow thanks for your answer.